# Firewall rules for outgoing RSH connections

Tags: centos, firewall, remote-access

I have a CentOS 6 server that needs rsh access to one of our old legacy servers which does not support ssh.

RSH connects to port 514 on the remote servers, which then creates another connection back to the client on a port between 512-1023. My current firewall skill level is "port open/port closed" and opening up all of them wouldn't leave much of a firewall. What's the most restrictive way to allow outgoing RSH connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd restrict the incoming from the range of servers using `iptables -A INPUT --src {IP address or range}/{netmask} -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 514:1023 -j ACCEPT`.

You can then restrict the incoming port ranges to the right servers

Unless you need to restrict outgoing data from a specific server I would not worry about setting up outbound rules.

I use webmin to set up my basic rules then I copy them manually (its faster and it saves me from looking up all the information I don't use regularly).  Webmin supports all sorts of rules--inbound, outbound and mangle.  You can set webmin up on a test box then edit then write the rules and copy them to the proper server.

Comment: I had to use `-I INPUT 8` instead of `-A INPUT` to place it before the catch-all reject rule, but this did the trick

Comment: I'm glad its working

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 with rsh-redone-client/server packages installed, rsh/rlogin to another host in LAN (running CentOS 6) was blocking for a long time (ca. 30 secs) until I opened port 113 (auth) in the local firewall for incoming connections from LAN. I am not sure how it was eventually (after those ~30 sec) working event w/o port 113 opened. Probably the server allowed the connection after some timeout anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Some old services include a feature that will send a username query back to the client host on each incoming connection. Services that I've seen to include this feature:

- FTP on old proprietary Unix servers
- rsh/rlogin/rexec
- IRC

The username query has a destination TCP port 113, originally known as `auth` port, later renamed to `ident` as it was recognized that it had nothing to do with any real authentication. In the early days of Internet, when most of the TCP/IP-connected systems were multi-user Unix systems, this service took as input the IP address and source + destination port numbers of another TCP connection, and looked up the client-side username associated with the connection.

Today, such a blindly trusting, easily spoofable disclosure of usernames is obviously not a good thing.

In most cases, the service that is making the `ident`/`auth` query will accept that the information is not available - but you must either accept or reject the query: if you just drop it, the user will see connection delays of up to 30 seconds, until the server-side gives up. The optimal rejection would be similar to what would happen if a host has no firewall in place, but has no service listening in TCP port 113, i.e. a TCP Reset packet.

For iptables rules, this means you should use a `REJECT` rule rather than `DROP` for TCP port 113, if you are using any legacy services that still send out `ident` queries.

Something like this should reject the `ident` queries in a way that will minimize the delays:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 113 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

If you are afraid that someone might abuse this to generate a denial-of-service attack, you can add a rate-limiting rule for TCP port 113 before this rule. But I understand the most modern network drivers will already handle the sending of TCP Reset responses as a very low priority task by default anyway, so it might not be a very significant risk.